# How to find is vector paralel to a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I hope that i could receive some help with the next problem:

I am having a trouble with finding is vector $(2, 2, 0, 1)$ parallel to linear map $\mathcal{L} = \left\{ (-2, 1, 0, 0), (\frac{-5}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1) \right\}$. Vector and linear map are in $\Bbb{R}^4$.

Is it right if i find the orthogonal projection of the given vector on the linear map and than check if the vector of the orthogonal projection could be translated to the $(2, 2, 0, 1)$?

Comment: The title of your question is confusing. Could you improve it?

Comment: I will try, immediatelly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{L}=\left\{\lambda (-2,1,0,0)+\mu \left(-\frac{5}{2},0,\frac{1}{2},1\right),\forall\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

A generic vector of $\mathcal {L}$ is then

$x=\left(-2 \lambda-\frac{5 \mu}{2},\lambda,\frac{\mu}{2},\mu\right)$

There are no $\lambda,\mu$ such that $x\parallel (2, 2, 0, 1)$

that is $\left(-2 \lambda-\frac{5 \mu}{2},\lambda,\frac{\mu}{2},\mu\right)=k\,(2, 2, 0, 1)$

Indeed the following system has no solutions except $\lambda=0,\mu=0,k=0$

$
\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {-2 \lambda-\frac{5 \mu}{2}=2k} \\ 
  {\lambda=2k} \\ 
  {\frac{\mu}{2}=0} \\ 
  {\mu=k} 
\end{array}} \right.
$

Hope this helps